# Error message: Can not set Integer field to java.lang.Class

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I was running in some strange error message while defining a domain-model in Grails and applying a constraint to an integer variable.

```
package example

class Ip {

String inetAddress
String DNS
Integer Points


String toString(){
    "${inetAddress}"
}

static constraints = {
    inetAddress()
    DNS()
    Points(nullable: true)

  }
```

}

This created the following error message when starting the application

```
 Message:Can not set org.springsource.loaded.ISMgr field example.Ip.r$fields to java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the variable definition from

```
 Integer Points
```

to

```
 Integer points
```

solved the problem.

Comment: seems that "Points" is handled as an object and "points" as a property value. And objects are not allowed to be null